# two different home is showing inside my dashboard?

Tags: admin-bar

[image]

why i'm getting another home as my sites and again druk country explorer  as another home.
and how can i remove the the first one

Comment: Looks like your site is part of a [WordPress Multisite](https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) network. The "My Sites" tab will show you other sites your account has access to on that network.

Comment: how e the can i remove the multisite network

Comment: Did you set up the website or did someone do it for you? If someone did it for you you're going to have to talk to them.

Comment: i did  it.. this website was at joomla  but i created template in wordpress.

Comment: Take a look at the link in my first comment. At some point during your install `define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );`  and probably a few more things were added to your wp-config file. 

If you used a "one click" installer you probably chose a multisite one by accident. If you  installed it yourself you must have followed the steps I linked to in my first comment.

Extracting a single site from a multisite install [can be difficult](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30103/convert-a-multisite-wordpress-install-into-a-single-site).

Comment: im just confuse how can i remove this things

Comment: you may just want to make a new install and use the post import/export tool. to move your existing content.

Answer (score 0):

The "My Sites" icon allows you to switch between multiple wordpress sites which you have associated to your admin account.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Dashboard_My_Sites_Screen